# Incessant mind chatter and narcissistic parents

Tags: krishna, philosophy, belief, mind, parents

This really is a personal question but It needs a spiritual angle so that I could be set free from this endless cycle. My parents are not proud enough of me no matter what I accomplish and what I achieve. This never ending need for seeking approval, getting attention and validation from them despite societal pressure which influences them every day eats me every single day. I fall into a self destructive pattern and downside spiral blaming myself and hating myself to a point that I could never make them proud. I really do not know a single soul on this planet who could understand the plight.
They always find someone from this modern society who did good, always pleasing when it is nothing compared to my accomplishments.
I tried avoiding all these, but they took an imprint in my mind. Suggest me something from the Holy Scriptures, please.